# Firefox does not shows saved bookmarks, addons while launching?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, firefoxdriver

When I am running software web application's tests In Firefox Browser using selenium WebDriver, It Is not showing me any bookmarks, addons, saved passwords etc in that browser.
Have you observed this?

> Do you know why this is with only Mozilla (FF) not in IE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC selenium webdriver creates a fresh FF profile each time it's constructed.

I found [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031253/what-profile-does-selenium-webdriver-use-by-default) about how to set it to a different profile (one where your bookmarks, addons etc. exist)

Regarding IE, I imagine profiles with IE more difficult perhaps?

Why would you want this though? I can maybe understand why you'd want a particular addon to see how it affects your web application, but bookmarks and saved passwords?

Answer (score 4):

> Yes absolutely right.

Because all those bookmarks, addons, passwords etc.. are saved In your regular browser's profile folder so when you launch browser manually, It will use existing profile settings & It will show you all those stuffs.

But when you run your software web application's tests In selenium webdriver, It Is opening new browser Instance with blank profile. So It will not show you bookmarks, addons..etc all those things In that browser Instance.